# В codeigniter jquery при повторном запросе ссрабатывает csrf-защита

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, csrf

Всем привет,
В codeigniter 3.1.0/bootstrap/jquery проекте, ENVIRONMENT=development 
при

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = true;
```

Я создаю нового пользователся через ajax вызов :

```
    var HRef = " base_url main/make_register"
    var register_data=  { username : encodeURIComponent(register_username),  email : encodeURIComponent(register_email), password : encodeURIComponent(register_password), first_name : encodeURIComponent(register_first_name), last_name : encodeURIComponent(register_last_name), phone : encodeURIComponent(register_phone), company : encodeURIComponent(register_company), capture : encodeURIComponent(register_capture),  csrf_token_name  : ' csrf_token_hash ' }

    alert( HRef+"  register_data::"+var_dump(register_data) )
    $.ajax({
        timeout: 10000,
        async :false,
        url: HRef,
        type: "POST",
        data: register_data,
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(result){
        alert( "result::"+var_dump(result) )
                        ...
    });
```

В контроле make_register есть проверки на уникальность  имени и емейла
и если ошибка, то возврашаются json описание ошибки.
Но при повторном сабмите формы я получаю ошибку :

> An Error Was Encountered
>       The action you have requested is not allowed

Это как раз сработала csrf-защита.
Отключать ее не стоит. Подскажите, а как можно тут лучше сделать ?
Или есть более удобные средства проверки валидности данных ?

Спасибо!

Comment: Единственная идея, которая пришла в голову - это выполнять 2 запроса : в 1ом делать проверку, во 2ом сохранять данные. Вероятность ошибки близка к нулю, но таки не нулевая.  Есть ли лучшее решение ?

Comment: Добавить роут аякса в белый список? Тогда для аякса не будет выполнятся проверка...